# How can I fix the 'instance of class Layer' error by creating LSTM with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, dictionary, keras, lstm, embedding

I'm creating a LSTM model with multiple categorical inputs. I've 169.856 samples, max 105 timesteps per sample (so I used paddings), and 2 categorical features. I've one label per sequence. Because the categorical inputs has to be encoded, I created for each an embedding layer, and after that I concatenate all of them. But, when I'm trying to add this concatenated layer to my sequential model, I get an error.

I already tried to put the input as arrays, instead of X_train I used [act, des], but when I'm doing that the validation doesn't work well. I also tried to create first a LSTM for each and after that concatenate the LSTMs.

```
#padDataAct and PadDataDes are like:
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 5, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 2, 5, 6],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 2, 2, 4]])

dataY = dataY
dataX = {'act': padDataAct, 'des': padDataDes}
num_act = len(data.action.unique())+1
num_des = len(data.DESCRIPTION.unique())+1
embedding_matrix_act = np.random.rand(num_act, 4)
embedding_matrix_des = np.random.rand(num_des, 4)
X_train = {'act': padDataAct[:traintestsplit], 'des': padDataDes[:traintestsplit]}
y_train = dataY[:traintestsplit]
X_valid = {'act': padDataAct[traintestsplit:], 'des': padDataDes[traintestsplit:]}
y_valid = dataY[traintestsplit:]

in_act=Input(shape=[105], name='act')
emb_act=Embedding(num_act, embedding_dim_act, mask_zero=True, weights = [embedding_matrix_act], input_length = 105, trainable = False)(in_act)
in_des=Input(shape=[105], name='des')
emb_des=Embedding(num_des, embedding_dim_des, mask_zero=True, weights = [embedding_matrix_des], input_length = 105, trainable = False)(in_des)

fe = concatenate([(emb_act), (emb_des)])
model = Sequential()
model.add(fe)
model.add(LSTM(36))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size=36,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

The error that occurs is:

> The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate_40/concat:0", shape=(?, 105, 4), dtype=float32)

Does anybody know how to solve this or what I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: not into tensorflow, what error is coming at  `model.add(fe)` when you are adding value to it. you need to check the `fe`, and make the class instance ( calling method) for input compatiable

Comment: @prashantrana thankyou. What do you mean with checking fe? Do you mean the shape? Now the shape is `TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(105), Dimension(4)])`. How can I make the class instance for input compatiable?

Comment: sorry i am not into tensorflow yet, but programmatically that is where you are getting error, you need to check the input which you are adding to model much be of same class  object which it require